# How to retrieve Bluetooth device from Bluetooth Settings in Android development?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm designing an app where I want the Bluetooth Settings to open with the click of a Button. Now while I'm on the settings, I will pair and connect to any bluetooth device nearby. When I press the back button & come back to app, I want to be able to retrieve that connected device as a BluetoothDevice in my app so I can manipulate it further from my app.

Now I know the searching, pairing & connecting can be done from the app itself using BluetoothAdapter, BluetoothSocket & BluetoothDevice, but I was wondering if there was any way to pair & connect using Bluetooth Settings & then get the connected device in my app.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to query bonded devices. But you will need to know the UUID or device name so that you get the correct paired device

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = adapter.getBondedDevices();
if (devices != null) {
    for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
        if (deviceName.equals(device.getName())) {
            result = device;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have your device, you can envoke `connect`